# React Native: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Alright, so I'm a bit new to react, and I've made a sample login screen like so:

```
export default class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login: '',
            password: '',
            // exists: false,
            Button: './submitButton.png',
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            //Login form here
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    styles = {styles.container}
                    placeholder = "Login"
                    onChangeText = {(login) => this.setState({login})}
                />
                <TextInput
                    styles = {styles.container}
                    placeholder = "Password"
                    onChangeText = {(password) => this.setState({password})}
                />
            </View>
            //Button here
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress = {() => Alert.alert("Alert!")}
                >
                    <Image
                        style={styles.button}
                        source={require('./submitButton.png')}
                    />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

But I get the error below:

[image]

Originally I had used a `Button` instead of `TouchableHighlight` because as I understand it, react-native 0.56 (the version I'm using) [has a bug regarding buttons](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20084), and *apparently* gives the same issue as above, and the workaround was supposedly to use a `TouchableHighlight` or `TouchableOpacity`. But switching to a `TouchableOpacity` didn't really seem to fix anything.

What do? I've scoured google but I can't seem to find a solution.

(If there's no hope, is there a way to downgrade my installation of react without breaking nearly everything?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JSX, comment like `//Login form here` doesn't work. It will be treated as a text.

You have to change your comments into the shape like below

```
{/* Login form here */}
```